# How the selection of the letter work in function replace /[aeiou/g]?

Tags: javascript

I made a code that select vowels and replace them with ""

```
function disemvowel(str) {
  str = str.replace(/[aeiouAEIOU]/g, "");
  return str;
}

console.log(disemvowel("This website is for losers LOL!"));
```

But I am not quite sure how this part of the code works =
`/[aeiouAEIOU]/g` why are the vowels inside [] and what the g does? as well as the //

Another question, how could I select both lower and upper case letter at once instead of right [aeiouAEIOU]?

Comment: `I made a code... I am not quite sure how this part of the code works...` You mean you copy-pasted some code and you don't know how it works :D

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```js
/[aeiouAEIOU]/g
```

is short for

```js
new RegExp( '[aeiouAEIOU]', 'g' )
```

It constructs a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object which represents a regular expression and some flags. A regular expression defines a set of strings. [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can use this definition to identify the substrings to replace.

The regex pattern

```
[aeiouAEIOU]
```

defines the following set of strings: `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `A`, `E`, `I`, `O`, `U`.

The `g` flag tells `String.prototype.replace` to replaces all instances of those substrings (not just the first).

Note that `/[aeiou]/ig` would be sufficient. The `i` flag makes operations case-insensitive. (This may have a performance penalty.)

Answer (score 1):

The code inside the `replace` method is a `Regular Expression` or `Regex`.

As described by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> Regular expressions are patterns used to match character combinations in strings. In JavaScript, regular expressions are also objects. These patterns are used with the exec() and test() methods of RegExp, and with the match(), matchAll(), replace(), replaceAll(), search(), and split() methods of String.

If you want to learn more about regex, I recommend taking a look at [this](https://regexr.com/) website. It helps you to write and visualise the patterns.